# Loading Javascript with AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have this neat little code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(function(){
 $(window).hashchange( function(){
   window.scrollTo(0,0);
   var hash = location.hash;
   if (hash == "") {
   hash="#main";
   }
     var newhash = !/\.php$/i.test(hash)? hash+".html": hash;
     ajax_loadContent('m',newhash.slice(1,newhash.length));
  $('.menu li a').each(function(){
     var that = $(this);
     that[ that.attr( 'href' ) === hash ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass' ]( 'current' );
  });
 })
 $(window).hashchange();
});

</script>
```

The only problem is that if I navigate to pages containing Javascript that code isn't being executed. How can I make it run the Javascript code as if the browser loaded the page normally?

Comment: Does it help?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888326/executing-javascript-script-after-ajax-loaded-a-page-doesnt-work

Comment: Currently I use parseScript found in that thread but all my functions from `<script type='text/javascript' src='scripts/gen_validatorv31.js'></script>` aren't loaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will not be execute as it comes as text. You have to use `"eval"` function on your response text

Comment: Not the whole response text is Javascript, it is a full page with html,styles and javascript.