# How to change all links in a page?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, hyperlink, userscripts

For pages like this IP-direct, Google search:

```
http://62.0.54.118/search?&q=42&oq=42&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&filter=0
```

How can I change all the links in that page from `search?q` to `search?&q=`?

For example, I want to make the link:

```
http://62.0.54.118/search?q=42&ei=Xf5bUqHLOKeQ0AWV4YG4Cg&start=10&sa=N&filter=0
```

into:

```
http://62.0.54.118/search?&q=42&ei=Xf5bUqHLOKeQ0AWV4YG4Cg&start=10&sa=N&filter=0
```

How can I make Chrome change the links by automatic script or something like that?

Comment: This question was not asked about, and did not even mention an AJAX scenario.  It's "not cricket" to alter a question fundamentally after it's been answered.

Comment: for those who are looking to change the color of the links (visited or not) on their browser: https://superuser.com/a/1489703/235752

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change those links, on a static page (like your example):

1. Search for applicable links.
2. Loop through the links and change them. (Typically using regex.)

**A complete userscript** would like like this:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _Modify select Google search links
// @include  http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @include  http://62.0.54.118/*
// ==/UserScript==

var qLinks  = document.querySelectorAll ("a[href*='?q=']");

for (var J = qLinks.length - 1;  J >= 0;  --J) {
    var oldHref = qLinks[J].getAttribute ('href');
    var newHref = oldHref.replace (/\?q=/, "?&q=");

    //console.log (oldHref + "\n" + newHref);
    qLinks[J].setAttribute ('href', newHref);
}
```

Save the file as `GoogleLinkModify.user.js` and then [drag it to the extensions page to install](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5258989/331508).  (Or install [the Tampermonkey extension](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo) and install the script via Tampermonkey).

---

## Important:

1. For AJAX-driven pages, install Tampermonkey and [use waitForKeyElements()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11197969/331508).
2. Google pages are a PITA to script.  Beware that even though you change the `href`, many Google pages will ignore that and also sneakily redirect links just as you click on them.  See or open other questions for more on that.

Comment: I was using your script and it work great till i reach that url: `http://62.0.54.118/search?&q=42&oq=42&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&filter=0#filter=‌​0&q=42&start=90` and every url that contain `#` in the site url, the script jammed..
*how can i make your script to work in place with `#`?
*how can i make use in waitForKeyElements() if nessecery? –

Comment: i had seen that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888326/executing-javascript-script-after-ajax-loaded-a-page-doesnt-work but didnt really realize how can i make use in that.

Comment: What do you mean by "the script jammed", ***exactly***?

Comment: the script work great, but when i press next, i get to that page `http://62.0.54.118/search?&q=42&oq=42&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&filter=0#filter=0&q=42&start=10`
)i believe its an ajax driven page(, and the script not apply..

Comment: That is, indeed, an ajax-driven page problem, over and above this question, as asked.  Mark this question answered and ask a new question for the AJAX problem if you can't figure out how to apply `waitForKeyElements()`.  Remember that you need Tampermonkey for that (on Chrome).  You should be using Tampermonkey anyway -- for the features and the ease.

Comment: /i dont know how to mark that question as answered, /i already  use Tampermonkey..
when i will open the new question, i will share a link of it to here..

Comment: ok, i will mark that as answer, in addition, here is my new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19376094/how-to-change-all-links-in-a-ajaxpage

Comment: please answer my new question i just asked, thanks:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19376094/how-to-change-all-links-in-a-ajaxpage

Answer (score 1):

Here is a regular expression that could work for you:

```
var url = 'http://62.0.54.118/search?q=42&oq=42&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&filter=0'
var regex = /(http:\/\/.*?search\?)(.*)/
console.log( url.replace(regex, '$1&$2') )

// 'http://62.0.54.118/search?&q=42&oq=42&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&filter=0'
```

You will need to loop through all the urls in the page and apply this to each of them.

Do you need help with modifying the HTML in the target page, or can you reach your solution from here?

Comment: i try to use that answer but without success, i enter at the url place javascript:youranswer and the links remain to be search?q= and not turn to be search?&q= as i want to..

Comment: in addition, i want that to work everywhere in the domain '62.0.54.118'.

Comment: For me, the links on the page your cited do not contain the string `'http://62.0.54.118/search?`. I have created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uMgRn/) which adds an `&` character after the `?` character. Does this do what you want?

Comment: i make your fiddle to work for me at http://jsfiddle.net/NnHUh/ but how can i apply that scripts to work on the links at http://62.0.54.118/search?&q=42&oq=42&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&filter=0
?

Answer (score 0):

A succinct one-liner that can be bookmarked as a scriplet:

```
javascript:for(i in dl=document.links)dl[i].href=dl[i].href.replace(/(http:.*search[?])(q=.*)/,'$1&$2')
```

ie. a simple way to observe traversed SO links, whether related or linked or raw, irregardless:

```
javascript:for(i in dl=document.links)dl[i].href=dl[i].href.replace(/[?].q=1/,"")
```