# How to change all links in an ajax driven page?

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, userscripts, tampermonkey

I have a userscript that modifies the href of all applicable links on an an IP-direct, Google search page:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _Modify select Google search links
// @include  http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @include  http://62.0.54.118/*
// ==/UserScript==

var qLinks  = document.querySelectorAll ("a[href*='?q=']");

for (var J = qLinks.length - 1;  J >= 0;  --J) {
    var oldHref = qLinks[J].getAttribute ('href');
    var newHref = oldHref.replace (/\?q=/, "?&q=");

    //console.log (oldHref + "\n" + newHref);
    qLinks[J].setAttribute ('href', newHref);
}
```

It works fine on the first page, but when I use the pagination links, it stops working -- because the new pages are loaded by AJAX.

@Brock Adams told me to use `waitForKeyElements()` but I couldn't figure out how to do it.

I have seen a few topics, like [stackoverflow.com/questions/10888326/executing-javascript-script-after-ajax-loaded-a-page-doesnt-work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888326/executing-javascript-script-after-ajax-loaded-a-page-doesnt-work), but I can't figure out how to use them.

How can I use that script to change links on an AJAX page like:

```
http://62.0.54.118/search?&q=42&oq=42&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&filter=0#filter=0&q=42&start=10
```

Comment: `search?g=` and `search?&g=` does not make a difference, both send a parameter named `g`…

Comment: first, the parameter is q, second, its metter to me because, if i didnt add the `&`, the search results redierct to other search engine because of my isp policy.., and if i add the `&` before the `q`, its stay in the original google search that i want..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change all links in a page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19362617/how-to-change-all-links-in-a-page) - your "new" question fits well into the scope of the first one, especially since the are so closely together time-wise. If you have something to add to your question, please do it there, instead of opening a new one for a topic that is so similar.

Comment: CBroe, i just do what -Bruck Adams- recommend me to..

`That is, indeed, an ajax-driven page problem, over and above this question, as asked. Mark this question answered and ask a new question for the AJAX problem if you can't figure out how to apply waitForKeyElements(). Remember that you need Tampermonkey for that (on Chrome). You should be using Tampermonkey anyway -- for the features and the ease. – Brock Adams 55 mins ago`

Comment: @CBroe, the question was asked and answered for a static page.  Only then did the OP realize that he needed an AJAX solution and that is a markedly new set of difficulties, especially on a Google site.  The static solution is fine for most pages, and simpler to understand. It's not the same question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change static-page code to use `waitForKeyElements()` you do 3 or 4 easy tasks:

1. Include jQuery and waitForKeyElements with the script's metadata section.
2. Choose the appropriate jQuery selector for waitForKeyElements.  It's often the same as what you would use for `querySelectorAll()`.
3. Adapt any loop-driven code for a single node. Leveraging jQuery as appropriate.
4. In this case, Google overwrites links, when you page, rather than use AJAX to place new ones.  So have the callback function return `true`.

Putting it all together, **the complete script** based on the question code would be:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _Modify select Google search links
// @include  http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @include  http://62.0.54.118/*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js
// @require  https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
/*- The @grant directive is needed to work around a design change
    introduced in GM 1.0.   It restores the sandbox.
*/
waitForKeyElements ("a[href*='?q=']", changeLinkQuery);

function changeLinkQuery (jNode) {
    var oldHref = jNode.attr ('href');
    var newHref = oldHref.replace (/\?q=/, "?&q=");

    jNode.attr ('href', newHref);

    return true;
}
```

Comment: See [your privileges page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges).  Voting up requires 15 points.

Comment: i need help in other qustion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19403763/how-can-i-combine-two-userscripts-into-one