# dynamically inserted javascript is not executing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

im trying to make a webapp that uses d-pad navigation so i work with keys on keyboard ,
for some reason i dont want to reload or redirect the page so i just change the content using ajax :

```
        var xhr;
        xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("GET","pages.php?page="+page ,  false);
        xhr.send();
        $('body').html(xhr.responseText);
```

ok it works fine and the content is replaces without problem but the javascript in the content is not executing...

NOTE: the reason i dont want to put javascript in the head section of the page is like i sad im working with keys and on diffrent pages i act diffrent with each keypress ...

Comment: what kind of javascript code are you injecting? you should make the calls to the code you added AFTER inserting it

Comment: Also why mix jQuery and initiating your own AJAX? If you're already using jQuery, you should use their relevant AJAX features

Comment: This seems like it shouldn't even be a problem in the first place. Can you elaborate on what your application is?

Comment: i use js to add an event listner for key presses and then i get the keycode for it ... so that i can do other things with that ...

Comment: @Blender its a web app for tv

Answer (score 0):

the problem over here is you are including all the content in your php page, with html and javascript code as html content to the body...which means as a text to the body it is appending the data. So your scripts won't work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Using the jquery get function:

```
$.get("pages.php?page="+page,function(data){
    $("body").html(data);
});
```

Comment: the problem is not about replacing the content ... the javascript works fine but the replaced code doesn't but thanks anyway

Comment: Sorry didn't read it properly, the other answers are much more useful.

Answer (score 0):

Just Make a Try,

May be you can make use of eval(), (But as said, eval is evil).

Refer this:
[Executing javascript script after ajax-loaded a page - doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888326/executing-javascript-script-after-ajax-loaded-a-page-doesnt-work)